# Use of a monad superclass in a monad instance declaration?

Tags: haskell, monads, lifting

I'm implementing a very simple poor mans concurrency structure with the following data type:

```
data C m a = Atomic (m (C m a)) | Done a
```

I'm creating an instance of monad for this:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (C m) where
  (>>=) (Atomic m) f      = Atomic $ (liftM (>>= f) m)
  (>>=) (Done v) f        = f v
  return                  = Done
```

Q1. Am I right in saying `Atomic $ (liftM (>>= f) m)` is creating a new `Atomic` monad which contains the result of `f` (`* -> *`) applied to the value inside of `m`?

Q2. Am I right in saying the superclass `Monad m` is used here to enable the use of `liftM`? If so, as this is an instance of the `Monad` class, why can't this access `liftM` directly?

Comment: NB `liftM` = `fmap` so you only need a `Functor` constraint. And your `C` is the same as the famous `Free` monad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1. It is creating `Atomic` **value**. Monad is a mapping at type level. Since `f` is the second argument of `>>=` of `C m a` we know its type

```
f :: Monad m => a -> C m b
```

hence

```
(>>= f) :: Monad m => C m a -> C m b
```

is `f` extended to unwrap its argument, and

```
liftM (>>= f) :: (Monad m1, Monad m) => m1 (C m a) -> m1 (C m b)
```

simply lifts the transformation into `m1` which in your setting is unified with `m`. When you extract the value `m` from `Atomic` and pass it to `liftM` you use the monad `m`'s bind (via `liftM`) to extract the inner `C m a` to be passed to `f`. The second part of `liftM`'s definition re-wraps the result as a `m (C m b)` which you wrap in `Atomic`. So yes.

Q2. Yes. But it is a `liftM` of the underlying monad `m`. The `liftM` for `C m a` is defined in terms of the instance (its `>>=` and `return`). By using `C m a`'s `liftM` (if you managed to define `>>=` in terms of `liftM`) you would get a cyclic definition. You need the constraint `Monad m` to create the plumbing for `m (C m a)` to travel through the `>>=` and `f`. In fact as pointed by Benjamin Hodgson, `Monad m` is an unnecessarily strong constaint, `Functor m` would suffice. The fact that `C` is in fact [`Free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free) together with the relevant [implementations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#line-189) give the most insight in the matter.

Comment: Re: Q1. So `Atomic (Maybe (Done v))` becomes `Atomic (Maybe (Done (f v)))`?

Comment: Your definition peels the `Done`. `Atomic (Just (Done v)) >>= f` becomes `Atomic (Just (f v))`.